# How to Crawl documents (.pdf, .docx etc.) with Storm Crawler

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

I am using Storm crawler 1.10.I am trying to include crawler to crawl documents too. I added tika parser based upon some research but the crawler not grabbing the *.pdf* urls. When I apply the tika the functions,new line(\n) inside the html pages is crawling that's looks weird when I check in the kibana.  There is no restrictions for documents in the regex.I'm sharing my configuration.  Anyone can help me in this situation that only crawl documents.

```
**es-crawler.flux:**
name: "crawler"

includes:
    - resource: true
      file: "/crawler-default.yaml"
      override: false

    - resource: false
      file: "crawler-conf.yaml"
      override: true

    - resource: false
      file: "es-conf.yaml"
      override: true

spouts:
  - id: "spout"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.persistence.AggregationSpout"
    parallelism: 10

bolts:
  - id: "partitioner"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.URLPartitionerBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "fetcher"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.FetcherBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "sitemap"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.SiteMapParserBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "parse"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.JSoupParserBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "index"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.bolt.IndexerBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "status"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.persistence.StatusUpdaterBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "status_metrics"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.metrics.StatusMetricsBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "redirection_bolt"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.tika.RedirectionBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "parser_bolt"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.tika.ParserBolt"
    parallelism: 1  

streams:
  - from: "spout"
    to: "partitioner"
    grouping:
      type: SHUFFLE

  - from: "spout"
    to: "status_metrics"
    grouping:
      type: SHUFFLE     

  - from: "partitioner"
    to: "fetcher"
    grouping:
      type: FIELDS
      args: ["key"]

  - from: "fetcher"
    to: "sitemap"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE

  - from: "sitemap"
    to: "parse"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE

  - from: "parse"
    to: "index"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE

  - from: "fetcher"
    to: "status"
    grouping:
      type: FIELDS
      args: ["url"]
      streamId: "status"

  - from: "sitemap"
    to: "status"
    grouping:
      type: FIELDS
      args: ["url"]
      streamId: "status"

  - from: "parse"
    to: "status"
    grouping:
      type: FIELDS
      args: ["url"]
      streamId: "status"

  - from: "index"
    to: "status"
    grouping:
      type: FIELDS
      args: ["url"]
      streamId: "status"
  - from: "parse"
    to: "redirection_bolt"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE


  - from: "redirection_bolt"
    to: "parser_bolt"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE


  - from: "redirection_bolt"
    to: "index"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE


  - from: "parser_bolt"
    to: "index"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE

  - from: "redirection_bolt"
    to: "parser_bolt"
    grouping:
      type: LOCAL_OR_SHUFFLE
      streamId: "tika"
```

---

```
**pom.xml:**
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.saunderstika.test1</groupId>
    <artifactId>saunderstika</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                    <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
                    <includePluginDependencies>false</includePluginDependencies>
                    <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>org.apache.storm.flux.Flux</mainClass>
                                    <manifestEntries>
                                        <Change></Change>
                                        <Build-Date></Build-Date>
                                    </manifestEntries>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <!-- The filters below are necessary if you want to include the Tika 
                                module -->
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                                <filter>
                                    <!-- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-2428 -->
                                    <artifact>org.apache.storm:flux-core</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>org/apache/commons/**</exclude>
                                        <exclude>org/apache/http/**</exclude>
                                        <exclude>org/yaml/**</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-crawler-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-crawler-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-crawler-tika</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>flux-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

---

```
**es-injector.flux:**
name: "injector"

includes:
    - resource: true
      file: "/crawler-default.yaml"
      override: false

    - resource: false
      file: "crawler-conf.yaml"
      override: true

    - resource: false
      file: "es-conf.yaml"
      override: true

components:
  - id: "scheme"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.util.StringTabScheme"
    constructorArgs:
      - DISCOVERED

spouts:
  - id: "spout"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.spout.FileSpout"
    parallelism: 1
    constructorArgs:
      - "."
      - "seeds.txt"
      - ref: "scheme"

bolts:
  - id: "status"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.persistence.StatusUpdaterBolt"
    parallelism: 1
  - id: "parser_bolt"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.tika.ParserBolt"
    parallelism: 1

streams:
  - from: "spout"
    to: "status"
    grouping:
      type: CUSTOM
      customClass:
        className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.util.URLStreamGrouping"
        constructorArgs:
          - "byHost"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set *jsoup.treat.non.html.as.error: false* in the configuration? See [README](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/external/tika/README.md) in Tika module.

I tried your Flux topology and I can see PDF docs being indexed, not sure where your problem is. Maybe try with a MemorySpout on a PDF URL e.g.

```
spouts:
  - id: "spout"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.spout.MemorySpout"
    parallelism: 1
    constructorArgs:
      - ["http://blog.marc-seeger.de/assets/papers/thesis_seeger-building_blocks_of_a_scalable_webcrawler.pdf"]
```

and check in the log and ES index that you are getting the document correctly.

Alternatively you can try using only Tika for the parsing instead of the JSoup parser, so that it handles all docs regardless of their mimetypes. It does not work as well as JSoup for Xpath extraction, which is why the latter is the preferred option for HTML content.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added *jsoup.treat.non.html.as.error: false* in the crawler-conf.

Comment: Hi Julien, I missed tika parser configuration in CrawlTopology and I added those changes\. Now I am able to index pdf documents.